# Best way for Interprocesses Communication between vxWorks application and .net Desktop application over TCP/IP

Tags: .net, tcp, ipc, rpc, vxworks

I have a vxWorks application Running on CurtisWright 194 board with  PPC processor.

On the other side I have a .Net Desktop application Running on a Windows PC.

Both host machines are connected to a local network using TCP/IP (Ethernet cable).

I can Exchange data between the two applications using RPC but I would like to know if there is a better way (a simpliest and more modern approach) for this scenario.

Thanks in advance,

Davide

Comment: REST, DDS maybe...

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Searching on web I saw that there are two implementations compatibile with vxWorks for the technologies you suggested:    
GoAhead web server https://www.embedthis.com/goahead/.  
RTI connext DDS https://community.rti.com/static/documentation/connext-dds/5.3.0/doc/manuals/connext_dds/getting_started_extras/RTI_ConnextDDS_CoreLibraries_GettingStarted_EmbeddedSystemsAddendum.pdf

Comment: Perhaps MQTT ? client libraries is  available for vxWorks. https://www.wolfssl.com/products/wolfmqtt/  and it seems to be free. I have not tested them, so not sure. I have worked on RTI DDS in past and it worked fine. MQTT is far simpler and the support is wider(1000x) than DDS.